# Error using heatmap.2 function

Tags: heatmap

I have a 47 X 49 dataframe which I converted to a matrix

```
dat=as.matrix(df)
```

But when I use

```
heatmap.2(dat)
```

its says

> `x' must be a numeric matrix.

I checked for NA values using `is.na(dat)` and its all `FALSE`.

Does anyone know this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem could be that the values in the dataframe where converted into strings instead of integers or floats, e.g.,

e.g.,

```
> df
  n  s
1 2 aa
2 3 bb
3 5 cc
> as.matrix(df)
     n   s   
[1,] "2" "aa"
[2,] "3" "bb"
[3,] "5" "cc"
```

So, what you could do is to remove all letter-containing columns from the matrix and use the apply function, e.g.,

```
> m = matrix(rep("3", 30), 5,6)
 > m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"
[2,] "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"
[3,] "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"
[4,] "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"
[5,] "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"
 > apply(m, 1,as.numeric)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    3    3    3    3
[2,]    3    3    3    3    3
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    3    3    3    3    3
[5,]    3    3    3    3    3
[6,]    3    3    3    3    3
```

Comment: Hm, this reminds me of a R heatmap tutorial that I have written some time ago, maybe this sections helps with the general transformation from CSV -> dataframe -> matrix procedure: http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/heatmaps_in_r.html#reading